# How to subtract entire rows from another (from different workbooks)?

Tags: excel, vba

When I'm in the same workbook, I know I can subtract rows from one another with

```
[A10:C10] = [A1:C1-A5:C5]
```

or

```
 ws.Range("A10:C10") = ws.Evaluate("A1:C1-A5:C5")
```

How do I do this if the ranges (here: `A1:C1` and `A5:C5`) aren't in the same workbook?

Comment: You will need to reference the other workbook.  How you do this will depend on if the workbook is open or not at the time the code is executed.

Comment: Range("A10:C10").Value = Evaluate("[Book1]Sheet1!A1:C1 - [Book1]Sheet1!A2:C2")